# Gatsby pages title doesn't refresh on page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

currently I'm working on a Gatsby app that generates all the pages from JSON files (I'm using Gatsby-Node's createPage action to do so). Everything works fine, there's only one small issue that I'm having and I can't quite figure it out.

In both development and production when I enter the page the title (and other metadata) are correct. Navigating to another page doesn't refresh the title (refreshing the page does change it to a proper one).

I'm using `react-helmet-async` currently, because `react-helmet` was throwing some warning about `componentDidMount` being deprecated. Using `react-helmet` fixes the issue on development but it doesn't fix the production (`gatsby serve`).

I'm using `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` and I've put it in `plugins` in the config file. Is there any additional configuration for the plugin that I need to have?

Note that not only the title doesn't change, but other metadata like description disappear on page change. I'm also using `Link` component imported from 'gatsby' (importing one from 'gatsby-link' broke all pages).

```
const Head = (props) => (
  <HelmetProvider>
    <Helmet>
      {props.title ? <title>{props.title}</title> : ''}
      {props.description ? <meta name="description" content={props.description} /> : ''}
    </Helmet>
  </HelmetProvider>
);
```

This is the component that sets the metadata. Any tips?